# Show a 30 M points 3D clouds using Python

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, lidar

I´d like to show a numpy array as a 3D scatter graphic.
This array has around 30 million points, it´s a LiDAR cloud.
I tried pyqtgraph but it took a lot of time and nothing was shown:

```
    plt = gl.GLScatterPlotItem(pos=p, color=C, size=10, pxMode=False)
```

Do you know some alternative?

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://vispy.org/ I've no experience with it, but from the docs it seems to do what you need.

Comment: I'd say you probably don't need to see all 30 million points. I'd slim your point cloud down via decimation (or some other means) before visualization.

Comment: I second @PeteGadomski and propose to make a row of tests with a growing number of actually plotted dots.  Don't forget that even a 4K display has only ~8M pixels.  I'd expect to get useful results by using less than 0.1% of your amount if data (still 30000 points).